# Difficulties using AJAX to pass input value to controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this PHP CodeIgniter code where in the view I am getting input from a text field. Using AJAC I am trying to pass this value to the controller using `GET` request. The controller will then call a function from my model to retrieve a database record matching the search criteria.

For some reason it doesn't work. I tried to do a var dump in the controller to see if the value is passed by AJAX, but I am not getting anything. Any ideas what I am doing wrong and why I can't receive the form value in the controller?

View:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.13.3/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script language="Javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submitbutton').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "../../index.php/testcontroller/getdatabasedata",
                data: {
                    'searchvalue' : $('#inputtext').val() 
                },
                method: 'GET'
            }).done(function (data) {
                var dataarray = data.split('##');
                $('#question').html(dataarray[ 1 ]);
                $('#answer1').html(dataarray[ 2 ]);
            });
            return false;
        });
    }); 
</script>  
</body>
```

Controller

```
public function getdatabasedata()
{
    $this->load->model('testmodel');
    $year = $this->input->get('searchvalue');
    //I TRIED TO DO A VARDUMP($YEAR) BUT I DON'T GET ANYTHING!

    $movie = $this->testmodel->findquestion($year);
    $moviesstring = implode(",", $movie);
    echo $moviesstring;
}
```

Model

```
function findquestion($searchvalue)
{
    $this->db->where('answer1', $searchvalue);
    $res = $this->db->get('questions');
    var_dump($res)
    if ($res->num_rows() == 0)
    {
        return "...";
    }
    $moviearray = $res->row_array();
    return $moviearray;
}
```

Comment: We need more detail to be able to help you. There are hundreds of reasons that an AJAX request could fail. The best thing to do would be for you to check the network tab of the console and let us knowwhat the status code of the request is.

Comment: What happens when you var_dump   $this->input? do you get anything?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan How can I check this? Which console?

Comment: press on F12 to see the console for firefox , and ctrl + shift + j for chrome

Comment: @Nassim GET https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.13.3/jquery.min.js 
(index):33 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ (index):33

Comment: @Nassim Highlighted in red in the console: src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.13.3/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function () {

Comment: the jquery library is not loaded

Comment: @Nassim Managed to load the correct library. No errors, but still no results when submitting the form.

Comment: ok comment all the lines in ur getdatabasedata() method and just echo "hello"  and see, if you see a hello in an alert box, that means u have a problem in ur model , if u don't see a hello in an alert box, comment the data line in the ajax code and see

Comment: @Nassim I don't get any message, and can't submit the form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98449/discussion-between-nassim-and-otonel).

Answer (score 1):

Script:

```
<script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script language="Javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  $("#submitbutton").bind("click",function() 
    { 
      var target_url = '<?php echo(base_url()."testcontroller/getdatabasedata") ; ?>';
      var data = {'searchvalue' : $('#inputtext').val() }; 
      $.ajax ({

              url : target_url, 
              type: 'GET', 
              data: data, 
              cache: false, 
              success: function(controller_data)
                { 
                  var dataarray = controller_data.split('#'); 
                  $('#question').html(dataarray[1]); 
                  $('#answer1').html(dataarray[3]); 
                }, 
            }); 
            return false; 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

> .bind("click",function()  - add quotes to click event.
>
> var dataarray = controller_data.split('#'); - split
>   data caracter must match character in implode function in controller.

Controller:

```
public function getdatabasedata(){

        $this->load->model('testmodel');
        $year = $this->input->get('searchvalue');
        $movie = $this->testmodel->findquestion($year); 
        $separated = implode("#", $movie);
        echo $separated;

    }
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: nice variable names ! (data_to_be_sent, data_that_came_from_controller)

Comment: @Nassim I just realised now their naming. changed them to something more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I will share my usual ajax code that I use in my views , make sure your base url is correct

```
$("#submitbutton").bind("click",function()
        {

            var target_url = '<?php echo(base_url()."testcontroller/getdatabasedata") ; ?>';
            $.ajax
            (
            {
                url : target_url,
                type: "GET",
                // data: {'searchvalue' : $('#inputtext').val()},
                cache: false,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert("error during loading ....");
                }
            });

        });// end loading via ajax
```

and in your controller just echo something

```
public function getdatabasedata()
{
    //$this->load->model('testmodel');
    //$year = $this->input->get('searchvalue');
    //I TRIED TO DO A VARDUMP($YEAR) BUT I DON'T GET ANYTHING!

    //$movie = $this->testmodel->findquestion($year);
    //$moviesstring = implode(",", $movie);
    //echo $moviesstring;
    echo "hello";
}
```